# Correct syntax for invoking a macro function within a macro

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Let us say I write a SAS macro and in that macro, I wish to invoke the macro function TRIM.
Do I need to write:

%sysfunc(%trim(&text.))

Or %trim(&text.)

Or
%sysfunc(trim(&text.))

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: %sysfunc(trim(&text.)) is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic rule regarding SYSFUNC or not SYSFUNC:

If you are running a function from [this page, the Dictionary of SAS Functions and Call Routines](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/67960/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1mj2bizbsd7ktn1sf9lz111kku3.htm), then you use `SYSFUNC`.

If it's on [this page](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/67912/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p06poki1icvtx7n19uf8jnx20pjb.htm) or the related pages ("Autocall Macros" is relevant here), then you use `%` and don't use `SYSFUNC`.

In some cases, and `%trim` is one of them, you can do *both* - getting more or less the same result (there may be small differences in how the SYSFUNC and the autocall macro work, particularly related to macro quoting).

Comment: I can do both and that is what confused me...thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

There is no macro function trim. So it depends on whether you want to call the SAS supplied autocall macro `%TRIM()` or if you want to use the function `TRIM()`.  If the later then you need to nest it inside the macro function `%SYSFUNC()` using `%SYSFUNC(TRIM())`.